# Cordova and ubuntu phone local storage not always persistent

Tags: cordova, ubuntu

I created an application for Ubuntu phone with Cordova last week.

Some users tell me (I also have the issue too), that parameters are not persistent. After close/open the app, parameters are not restored.

It is not happens everytime and seems to be random.

To save data, I use :

```
localStorage.setItem("parameter",value);
```

Do I need to commit or something ?

Full project is accessible here : https://github.com/Inglebard/YAOSWA.

Local storage read/write is done in this file : https://github.com/Inglebard/YAOSWA/blob/master/www/js/app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue from ubuntu-phone webview.

Answer (score 0):

Use [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage), it is very persistent with cordova and angular applications.

Comment: Hi mudasser ajaz, I try the plugin. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue. It seems to come from how Cordova manage local storage.

Comment: Did you try both localstorage and sessionstorage with angular-local-storage?

Comment: Session storage can't be use for persistent storage : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp